# Shared Preferences on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use **Shared Preferences** but I have this strange behavior.

Im using:

```
shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+2
```

On a **StateFull Widget** on the **initState** I have this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _testing()
  }


Future<void> _testing() async{
 print("starting")
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 await prefs.setInt('value', 1);
 print("saved?")
}
```

When I run the code with flutter run, I only get the print for "starting", not for "saved?".

The same exact code Im using for this project I've used to build an Android App and it worked just fine. But for iOS is not working.

What I am missing?

Comment: Don't you have to mark the `_testing` function `async`? (You should also give it a return type, e.g. `Future<void>`) I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: Hello @RichardHeap, Yes it has the async, edited the question with the correction. I've added the Future<void> for the function, and still only printing the "starting" msg

Answer (score 0):

It works, there are no errors. Copy & paste and try it again:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  saveValue() async{
    print("Starting...");
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('value', 1);
    print("Saved?");
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    saveValue();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Shared Preferences")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: After Add shared_preferences: ^2.0.6 My Code not working in Xcode. Pls Help. Its working in Android

Answer (score 0):

It won't print because you are using the await before setting the int value.

```
await prefs.setInt('value', 1);
```

If you remove the await , then try checking the print value it will work fine.

Let me know if it works.